# Mysqli_real_escape_string not recognizing link

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli_real_escape_string to clean my user input before inserting it into my database. I have used it before without trouble, but for some reason this time it is not recognizing my link identifier.

```
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//Function to sanitize the values received from the form (prevents SQL injection)
function clean($str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    $rtstr = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
    return $rtstr;
}
```

For some reason when I try to input information through this file, it gives me the error "Undefined variable: link" and then "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli" for every time it encounters this function.

I am very confused because everything seems to be correct, but I can't find a way around this error. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or is it something outside of this code causing the issue?

Comment: Have you written all these code within a single file? Or is the connection in another file, and maybe you haven't included that one in this second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `$link` in your function but it is not defined in your function. 
You have to pass it as a parameter or define it in the function.

Then, you have to call your function.

```
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
}
//Function to sanitize the values received from the form (prevents SQL injection)
function clean($str,$link) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    $rtstr = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
    return $rtstr;
}

clean('test',$link);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was converting this from an old mysql function and didn't even think of that. Good eye! I'll give you the check in 10min when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare global $link within your function.

```
function clean($str) {
  /* Other code */
  global $link; // Add this
  $rtstr = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
  return $rtstr;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD